# Método main em JFrame?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

eu tenho uma dúvida:
Ao criar um novo JFrame no Netbeans, é colocado um método main dentro deste, achei que fosse necessário e portanto nunca mexi no mesmo. Hoje eu o apaguei e o programa continuou funcionando normalmente. A pergunta é: QUANDO o método main de um JFrame é usado no programa? Detalhe que o método principal do projeto é de uma classe de controle e portanto teoricamente o main do JFrame não é executado. Estou certo?

Comment: No primeiro nível de uma aplicação só deve existir um JFrame, por isso esse método main seria a entrada da sua aplicação. É má prática de programação usar mais que um JFrame. Todos os programas em Java começam no método **main**.

Comment: Após o uso do JFrame como seria o correto proceder? Utilizando JPanel?

Comment: Veja [aqui](https://terminaldeinformacao.com/2013/05/22/entendendo-os-principais-componentes-de-um-jframe/).

Answer (score 0):

O metodo main é necessário para seu jFrame principal, ou sua classe responsável por instanciar um jFrame..

é bom ter um main() nos jFrames, já que ao tentar compilar somente aquele jFrame em si ele precisa desse main para iniciar. A não ser que a cada teste que voce queira fazer precise compilar o projeto inteiro e a partir do seu jFrame principal ir abrindo os outros...

Comment: Obrigado agora entendi! Agradeço pelas respostas!